# Django form class never appear in template

Tags: python, django, templates, url, view

View function to represent the form, never appear in template.
This is my from class

```
from django import forms

class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    search_compNum = forms.CharField(label='Compound_Number', max_length=10)
    search_formula = forms.CharField(label='Molecule_Formula')
    search_format = forms.CharField(label='InChI or Smiles', widget=forms.Textarea)
```

This is the view function.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import SearchForm

def get_query(request):
""" molecule search form. """

    form_class = SearchForm

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            Query_Compound_Number = request.POST.get('search_compNum', '')

    else:
        form_class = SearchForm()

    return render(request, 'search.html', {'form': form_class})
```

This is a template.

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <form action="{% url 'chemdb:results' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

And the urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^index/$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^search/$', views.SettingView.as_view(), name='search'),
    url(r'^search/$', views.DataBaseView.as_view(), name='search'),
    url(r'^search/$', views.SortView.as_view(), name='search'),
    url(r'^search/$', views.TypeView.as_view(), name='search'),
    url(r'^search/$', views.FilterView.as_view(), name='search'),
    url(r'^search/$', views.get_query),
    url(r'^results/$', views.result, name='results')
]
```

And I'm using Django 1.8.x version. So, I don't need to import 'pattern'.
Help me plz!!!!

Comment: You have six views mapped to the same URL. That can't possibly work.

Comment: Wow. Thank you!! I solved the problem!